# Patent overseas

Tags: patent-applications, pct, foreign

I am filing a patent overseas in China. My U.S. Attorney need me to sign a power of attonery to the attonerys in China. The language in the contract states: pursuant of the relevant provisions of the Patent Law of the People's Republic of China, I , citizen entity of the USA hereby authorize Prominence CENFO Intellectual Property Agency Limited to appoint its patent attorney to apply on my behalf for utility patent registration for the invention entitled.

Whose international application number is and handle all related matters concerning about the patent right in progress of designated office or selected office.

My concern the language is too broad.

Comment: Why not ask your attorney about the contract language?

Comment: The last sentence in your question seems to be cut off.

Comment: I ask my attonery and he said its standard for China and I can revoke the POA anytime.

Comment: I just wanted a second opinion and see if anyone experince the same situation

Comment: I'm not a lawyer so I can't provide a qualified answer. Your attorney can.

Comment: What makes it broad, in your thinking? What do you think this lets them do that you do not want to authorize?

Comment: China and US relations is in discord. I want to protect my idea as much as possible to prevent billion dollar industries making a profit that I created.